# tx_news: Change language of news to ALL, sys_file_reference does not change

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

Some of my news are used on different languages. To archive that I need to set the language of this news to ALL (ID: `-1`). When I do that the news works, but the Image does not work, because the Image is a sys_file_reference and this does not change the language. Also there is no field to change the language of the image at all in the backend, so I need to do this in the database.

I found a bug report for this problem:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/48883

And I use the "fix" from the bug report so that at least it is possible to change the langauge in the backend:

```
$TCA['sys_file_reference']['palettes']['filePalette']['isHiddenPalette'] = 0;
```

(This goes into the ext_tables.php of your template).

Anyway, this is not a good solution and editors will often forget to change the language of (all) the image(s).

Anyone found/know a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom function that you hook into DataHandler (the component that stores your backend forms in the database).

The tricky part here is that you need to modify a related record (the sys_file_reference) based on the type of your original record (the tx_news entry). DataHandler processes the records sequentially, as they are sent by the HTML form. The trick is that the base (news in your case) record always comes first, so you could use that information to find out when your custom logic needs to kick in.

In the custom hook, you could then use the language from the base record to set the language of the child records. One possible hook would be `processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray`. Registering such a hook is documented in TYPO3 core docs: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Hooks/Configuration/Index.html

Comment: Thanks alot for the infos. I never used a hook yet and I will need some testing first. I will leave the question open until I get some time to test it. May I ask you to take a look at another question of mine? Any idea if using a hook or so could solve that problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393398/backend-user-translate-content-from-default-language-was-not-allowed